# Are SUVs' headlights brighter than sedans'?

Tags: headlight

It'd be too unproductive to check every SUV's headlights' lumens and compare it with every sedan's.

I ask this for Canada and US.

Comment: See https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/60660/10976

Comment: So you think it would be unproductive in terms of your time - why expect us to do it with our time?

Comment: @SolarMike I don't. I was hoping that someone would know this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the type of headlights there are few types: HALOGEN, XENON (HID), LED, LASER. Usually led/laser ones seems to be the brightest, but this also depends on type of light bulb you have and so on.

Comment: SUV's may "seem" brighter as they tend to be higher so causing more dazzle...